# Convert to Codeigniter Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to write this query in codeigniter format?

```
SELECT rights_management.id, rights_management.tab_name FROM rights_management 
WHERE rights_management.id NOT IN (SELECT r_m.tabid FROM r_m)
```

Thanks for the Help . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your sub query in CI using `where` clause

```
$this->db->select('rights_management.id, rights_management.tab_name');
$this->db->from('rights_management');
$this->db->where('`rights_management.id` NOT IN (SELECT r_m.tabid FROM `r_m`)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to select r_m.tabid from table  r_m and store it in array.

```
 $this->db->select('r_m.tabid');
    $this->db->from('r_m');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $alb = $query->result_array();
```

Make it to an array

```
foreach($alb as $rs){
 $not_need[]=$rs['tabid'];
}
```

After that fire the general active class using where_not_in.

```
 $this->db->where_not_in('rights_management.id', $not_need);    
 $this->db->select('rights_management.id, rights_management.tab_name');
 $this->db->from('rights_management');
 $result= $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query('SELECT rights_management.id, rights_management.tab_name FROM rights_management WHERE rights_management.id NOT IN (SELECT r_m.tabid FROM r_m)');
```